# Custom directive doesn't shows {{variable}} value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have this Angular controller:

```
app.controller("timelineCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.user="john";
         .
         .
         .
}
```

And this directive:

```
app.directive('helloWorld', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div> Hello World {{user}} </div>'
    };
});
```

and this view:

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="timelineCtrl">
     <hello-world></hello-world>
</div>
```

but i get this in the result html:

```
Hello World {{user}}
```

Why `{{user}}` does not interpreted to `$scope.user` value?

Comment: It seems to work for me - http://plnkr.co/edit/u5ZRFZITnPIOCvQVyTk6?p=preview

Comment: Are you getting an error before this occurs? You should never see {{ }} inside a template when it's declared within a ng-app element. Even if the value doesn't exists. I would expect "Hello world" to be shown, even if user isn't declared in that scope.

Comment: @user2734679: it seems i have an error. i get this:
Error: Multiple directives [helloWorld, helloWorld] asking for 'helloWorld' controller on: <div>

Comment: Huh, I've never seen that error before. Do you have multiple directives in that app with the name 'helloWorld'?

Comment: Can you please add the complete script and html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach the controller to your directive definition.

```
app.directive('helloWorld', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        controller: 'timelineCtrl',
        template: '<div> Hello World {{user}} </div>'
    };
});
```

---

Edit; Given your latest edit I'm not so sure that is the problem, in any case - here's a [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/loxasadozu/1/edit?html,js,output) showing you how that works.

---

Just to clarify (for anyone that may be reading this); you dont **need** to attach the controller to your directive. You can, if you want to. There's nothing wrong in doing so - even if the directive doesn't supply it's own child/isolated scope.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you will have to elaborate. How is it not working? Can we see a stack trace? The output of your devtools? Saying you are doing what the bin is doing (which is working), and then saying it is not isn't really helpful (sorry).

Comment: When the the directive does not declare scope: {}, or scope: true, it shares the name controller scope as it's parent. You do not need specify a controller per directive.

Comment: You don't have to, but you certainly can and there's certainly nothing wrong with it. I'm giving the OP *options*, but - it would appear that the option of attaching a controller to a directive definition wasn't something you enjoyed very much.

Comment: @Kasper Lewau it seems i found why my code doesnt work. its my mistake. i loaded module JS file twise in html header and this is the cause of this error. sorry

Comment: Glad you found the monkey in your wrench. and/or that I was of some assistance here.